# Overriding CRUD in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Does Hibernate have something similar to to EclipseLink `DescriptorCustomizer`? I want to override CRUD operations with custom SQL

Comment: This question can be answered only by people knowing EclipseLink and Hibernate quite well. If you told us what you actually want to achieve, more people would be able to help you.

Comment: I want to use custom sql on EntityManager's persist/merge/remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA 2.1 supports [type convertors](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html) and Hibernate has [UserTypes](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/), so that you can customize the SQL to Java type mapping.

But since you said Overriding CRUD, Hibernate also defines:

- [SQLInsert](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert.html)
- [SQLUPdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLUpdate.html)
- [SQLDelete](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete.html)

to allow you to customize the insert/update/delete SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want. But can I use multiple insert statements and how?

Comment: Each entity is associated to one and only one database row. So, when you insert/update/delete an entity you usually issue only one database statement. The inheritance and secondary table associations are an exception to a rule.